# Android - "Fail to Connect to Camera Service" -- How to Clear / Reset?

Tags: android, camera

I'm experimenting with the Camera class.  During experimentation on my Samsung Galaxy Note phone (not emulator) to open the camera im getting the error **Fail to connect to camera service**.  I'm aware this was caused by my app not previously releasing the camera object.

I've tried stopping the debugging session and removing my app from the Application Manager but still the Camera.open(myCamId) refuses to return back a valid camera object.  And for the record this worked fine the first go around.

I'm confident i can get things moving again with a phone restart but is there a quicker way to release the previously opened camera object?  And no i cant simply release the camera object at this stage before re-opening bc the Camera.open is not returning ANY camera object to release.

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access, you can kill the mediaserver process. It will restart automatically, but most likely the camera will now get connected.

Answer (score -1):

No, as far as I know you have to reboot your phone.